# AjaxControltoolkit Html Extender custom fonts

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Has any one experience of embedding custom fonts in html extender in ajax control toolkit? Please guide me so i can embed some custom fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download [AjaxControlToolkit sources from Codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#), add desired fonts definitions to `_createButton` function in [HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior.Pre.js](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Client/MicrosoftAjax.Extended/HtmlEditorExtender/HtmlEditorExtenderBehavior.Pre.js) file, rebuild solution and use customized toolkit dlls.

Comment: Amazing man.. I was thinking the same. Already testing customization.